# CSS: How to set height of body element to fill rest of total height excluding variable length header and footer

Tags: html, css

I would like to make an html full-screen like pages having header, main, and footer element filling the window height.
And, I want to make the main element to fill the rest of height. So, main element's height should be (window height - header height - footer height).
Header and footer heights are not fixed.
I can make it work using JavaScript, but I feel it is better if possible to make resizing smooth just by CSS.

Here is what I'm trying, and Jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/yoshiokatsuneo/C53J3/

```
.header{
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
.main{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
.content{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


<div class="content">
    <img src="http://mrg.bz/ccyR3V" class="header">
    <img src="http://mrg.bz/qmVoy1" class="main">
    <div class="footer">
    Here is footer. height is not fixed.
    </div>
</div>
```

In this jsfiddle, I would like to make the main element fill between the header and  the footer.

Is there any idea?

Comment: What browsers you plan to target? (modern?)

Comment: Also... you did not pointed out the **most important thing**: what about the *main* area? what about scrolling? What if the content exceeds the *main* height? Where should than *Footer* go? You can expect a good answer only if you exactly know what you need and you covered all the possibilities.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm assuming modern HTML5 browsers like Safari7. And, I would like to fill main area between header and footer. I don't want to have scrolling area. I'm assuming that "header + main + footer" can fit within height. I'm thinking to make the page like one window native application where all the element just fix within the window.

Comment: So basically if I scroll the main content the footer will be always in place (visible at the bottom)?

Comment: Look I'm trying to help, if you don't participate you'll loose people interest in helping you...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, I don't want to have scroll bat at all, assuming window size is larger than header and footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CSS tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/C53J3/24/)**

...also, the main content doesn't have to be an `img`, it could be a `div` an ,`a` etc.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/C53J3/26/)**

```css
* {
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.header {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
.mainWpr {
    height: 100%;
}
.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.footer {
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display:table;
}
.content > div {
    display:table-row;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div>
        <img src="http://mrg.bz/ccyR3V" class="header" />
    </div>
    <div class="mainWpr">
        <img src="http://mrg.bz/qmVoy1" class="main" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="footer">
            Here is footer. height is not fixed.Here is footer. height is not fixed.Here is footer. height is not fixed.Here is footer. height is not fixed.Here is footer. height is not fixed.Here is footer. height is not fixed.Here is footer. height is not fixed.Here is footer. height is not fixed.Here is footer..</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But, it does not work for other than ing, like text area [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yoshiokatsuneo/f03ydsk5/)

Comment: @TsuneoYoshioka - please note that the example you gave in your question was with an img...

Comment: @TsuneoYoshioka - you just need to use a block element like a `div` for the main element OR add `display:block` - here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/C53J3/26/

Comment: It magically works ! And, I could not get it why it works. I guess the trick is height:100% in .mainWpr. What does "100%" means ? 100% of what ?

Comment: @TsuneoYoshioka - in tables when height:100% is set on one of the rows this ensures that it takes up the 'remaining height' what's left from the other rows

Answer (score -2):

Can you elaborate your question and what you want to achieve. 
also please try this one.

```
.header{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
height: 30px;
width: 100%;
}
.main{
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.footer{
position: fixed;
bottom: 100px;
width: 100%;

}
.content{
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This does not work as I intended. In this code, main element's height is the same as window heights. But, I want to set "main+header+footer" element's height height to window height.

Comment: I think konnection got what you wanted.Correct?

Comment: Not sure, but the jsfiddle konnection made does not work perfectly.